# Can I use Pointer to a Class?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am using Delphi XE3. And after studying the post [Delphi - Maintaining Self References to an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027244/delphi-maintaining-self-references-to-an-object) , I understand that a variable of a class type is actually a pointer that references an object.

Therefore, I write the following code to test that, as follows:

```
TMyClass = class
public
  constructor Create(Name: string);
  destructor Destroy;

  function GetName: string;

private
  FName: string;
end;

PMyClass = ^TMyClass;

constructor TMyClass.Create(Name: string);
begin
  FName := Name;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin

end;

function TMyClass.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := FName;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TMyClass;
  P: PMyClass;
begin
  Item := TMyClass.Create('Jim');

  P := PMyClass(Item);

  OutputDebugString(PWideChar(Format('Address of object: %x; Address of variable Item: %x; Value of P: %x;',
                            [Integer(Item), Integer(@Item), Integer(P)])));

  OutputDebugString(PWideChar(Format('Name is %s', [Item.GetName()])));
  OutputDebugString(PWideChar(Format('Name is %s', [P.GetName()])));
end;
```

In my code, using PMyClass(Item) seems also get the object address, since Integer(PMyClass(Item)) is same as Integer(Item). However, it seems that with the pointer to the object, I cannot invoke any method, both P.GetName() and P^.GetName() will cause access violation. Why?

And my question is, whether I can use pointer to class in programming. Also whether it is necessary to use pointer to class since a variable of a class type has already held the object address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PMyClass(Item)
```

This cast is wrong. Because `Item` is `TMyClass` but `PMyClass` is `^TMyClass`. Item cannot be both `TMyClass` and `^TMyClass`.

The invalid cast is why you encounter the access violation.

If you really did want to obtain a value that was `^TMyClass` then you would need to take the address of a `TMyClass` value. An example from your code would be `@Item`. So, `Item` is `TMyClass`, hence `@Item` is `^TMyClass`.

There are situations where `^TMyClass` might be useful, but they are not apparent in any of the code you present. For instance, you might use a variable of type `^TMyClass` to hold a reference to a variable of type `TMyClass`. In other words, the standard scenario where pointers are useful.

Answer (score 0):

`Item` already is pointer to the instance of `TMyClass` and you don't need to introduce excessive level of adressing.

`NativeInt(Item)` gives you the number representation of the address. To get the same representation from `P`, with proper type casting, you need to use `P = @Item` and `NativeInt(P^)`

I don't see how pointers might be useful for your task.... BTW, what is your real problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `NativeInt` instead of `Integer`, since a pointer might not fit in a 32-bit integer on a 64-bit platform?